# Cannot boot from bootable Windows USB

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed and I want to dual boot Windows 10. I downloaded the [official ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/hr-hr/software-download/windows10ISO) and flashed it using `dd`. The ISO was correctly flashed and verified with MD5. The `dd` command was:

```
sudo dd if=Win10_2004_EnglishInternational_x64.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=4M status=progress conf=fdatasync
```

On my PC (ASUS H97), it is not visible in the BIOS as a bootable drive. It is recognized as a "Mass Storage Device" and I cannot boot from it. I suppose this is because of the UDF format Microsoft uses. When I flash the drive as NTFS and copy paste the ISO files it is correctly recognized, but still won't boot.

Also, when I try to flash the ISO with etcher, the official Windows ISO, etcher complains

> It looks like this is not a bootable image. The image does not appear
> to contain a partition table, and might not be recognized or bootable
> by your device

I have the grub bootloader. Everything is updated to the latest version. How do I boot the Windows 10 installation?

Comment: See https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-from-Ubuntu for use of unetbootin . BTW, you *do* have a vlad license?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik You don't need a license to download and flash the ISO. But I do have a couple.

Comment: Unetbootin doesn't recognize my USB drive...

Comment: no, you need a license to *use* Windows after installing it... but you should be OK. As for the USB drive not being recognized, perhaps it's damaged or needs to be formatted... which could explain the issues you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create bootable windows usb simply by dd command as win iso images are non-bootable images(unlike linux iso images which are bootable).

Use [WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB)

**To install WoeUSB on ubuntu**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update
sudo apt install woeusb
```

For alternatives/other methods see :  [how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)